# Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

Hello when i inflate a view i got this error "Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class "
on 28 line i have this:

```
28<TextView
        android:id="@+id/QuantityProductInDoc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>
```

error:
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
05-18 08:45:13.200 1385-1385/company.aqua.it.salesdev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: company.aqua.it.salesdev, PID: 1385
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at company.aqua.it.salesdev.CustomListOfProductInDoc.getView(CustomListOfProductInDoc.java:39)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1685)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1732)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1497)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1732)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1497)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
I can not understand what the problem is. thanks.

Comment: share your whole error with question

Comment: What is line number 28?

Comment: Why you are setting android:layout_width="0dp"? width or height to 0dp then what it's use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried and I found your error

the Line `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"` is error.

Delete it and problem solved. Sorry for the wrong ans just nw